# Appending and Preloading Images with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm in the process of creating a site that preloads several large gifs. Due to the size of the images. I need them all to be loaded before displayed to the user. In the past I have done this numerous times using something basic like this:

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () { document.appendChild(image); }
image.src = '/myimage.jpg';
```

However, i'm loading a group of images from an array, which contains the image source url. It should show a loading message and once they have all loaded it show perform a callback and hide the loading message etc.

The code I've been using is below:

```
var images = ['image1.gif', 'image2.gif', 'image3.gif'];

function preload_images (target, callback) {        

    // get feedback container
    var feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

    // show feedback (loading message)
   feedback.style.display = 'block';

    // set target
    var target  = document.getElementById(target);

    // clear html of target incase they refresh (tmp fix)
    target.innerHTML = '';      

    // internal counter var
    var counter = 0;

    // image containers attach to window
    var img = new Array();

    // loop images
    if (images.length > 0) {

        for (var i in images) {

                // new image object
                img[i] = new Image();

                // when ready peform certain actions.
                img[i].onload = (function (value) {             

                // append to container
                target.appendChild(img[value]);             

                // hide all images apart from the first image
                if (value > 0) {
                    hide(img[value]);
                }               

                // increment counter
                ++counter;                  

                // on counter at correct value use callback!
                if (counter == images.length) {

                  // hide feedback (loading message)
                 feedback.style.display = 'none';

                  if (callback) {
                     callback(); // when ready do callback!
                  }

                }

            })(i);

            // give image alt name
            img[i].alt = 'My Image ' + i;

            // give image id
            img[i].id  = 'my_image_' + i

            // preload src
            img[i].src = images[i];             

        }//end loop

    }//endif length

}//end preload image
```

It's really weird, I'm sure it should just work, but it doesn't even show my loading message. It just goes straight to the callback.. I'm sure it must be something simple, I've been busy and looking at it for ages and finding it a tad hard to narrow down.

I've been looking over stackoverflow and people have had similar problems and I've tried the solutions without much luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'll post more code if needed.

Cheers!

Comment: I should mention that the array Images is an external/global array from this function

Comment: I think you are executing your onload callback function when it is being defined. (function(){})() will execute the code immediately.

Comment: ah of course! I'll try and rework my code and see what i can do. I'll post back my results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not totally wrong the problem is with you assignment to

```
// when ready peform certain actions.
img[i].onload = (function (value) {...})(i);
```

here you instantly call and execute the function and return undefined to the onload attribute, what can not be called when the image is loaded.

What you can do to have access to the value 'i' when the image is loaded you can try something like the following:

```
onload = (function(val){
    var temp = val;
    return function(){
         i = temp;
         //your code here
    }
})(i);
```

this should store the value in temp and will return a callable function which should be able to access this value.

I did not test that if it is working and there maybe a better solution, but this one came to my mind :)

Comment: This appears to be working! Thanks everyone for helping out. I need to run a few more tests to make 100% sure its all working correctly. I'll post back if I get different results. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your onload callback:

```
img[i].onload = function(event) {
    target.appendChild(this);

    if (img.indexOf(this) > 0) {
        hide(this);
    }

    // ...
};
```

Hope you can get it working! It's bed time for me though.

Edit: You'll probably have to do something about img.indexOf(this)... just realized you are using associative array for img. In your original code, I don't think comparing value to 0 is logical in that case, since value is a string. Perhaps you shouldn't use an associative array?